# How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure in ios flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am working on the flutter_downloader iOS configuration and I have no knowledge of swift. I am getting an error but I don't know how to solve it. Please suggest how can I format my code so it starts working properly. Below is my code of AppDelegate.swift:

```
 import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase
import flutter_downloader

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
     FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(registerPlugins)
     Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  private func registerPlugins(registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("FlutterDownloaderPlugin")) {
       FlutterDownloaderPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "FlutterDownloaderPlugin")!)
    }
}}
```

Comment: What error do you get and what line of code generates it?

Comment: line 15 and the error is "How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure"

Comment: This  line  FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(registerPlugins)

Comment: Are you sure that’s the error message, sounds more like a question to me. Anyway this seems like a Flutter related issue and I have no knowledge about that framework so I can’t help you.